# How can we add line above footer in pdf of datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable, pdfmake

I have the following code to add footer in pdf.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "dom": 'Bfirtlp',
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [0, 1, 2],
            },
            customize: function(doc) {
                var now = new Date();
                var jsDate = now.toGMTString();
                doc['footer'] = (function(page, pages) {
                        return {
                            columns: [{
                                    alignment: 'left',
                                    fontSize: '7',
                                    text: ['Version: 1.0']
                                }, {
                                    alignment: 'center',
                                    fontSize: '7',
                                    text: ['page ', {
                                        text: page.toString()
                                    }]
                                }
                                margin: 20
                            }
                        });
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

In the footer how can i add line above it?

Comment: my best guess would be to just add this code `{
                                    alignment: 'left',
                                    fontSize: '7',
                                    text: ""
                                }`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I want to add border above footer ,how this code will help?

Comment: First of you said `In the footer how can i add line above it` nothing about a border, Please include all relevant information in your question, else we will have a very hard time helping you.